# User defined value in session a security risk?

Tags: java, security, session, servlets

Is putting a value which the user can define/specify in a http session a security risk?

```
request.getSession().setAttribute(KEY,  
request.getParameter(usernameParameter));
```

If this is the case what can i do to solve this?

One thing i can think of is a huge value which fills up my harddisk/memory, but it seems a bit far fetched. Limiting the string length could solve this.

Comment: It is too late to worry about size at this point. Attributes already parsed and stored in memory at the moment when you get access to request.

Comment: @talex Request attributes are not saved for a long time, session attributes possible are. Isn't it possible for a user to create a huge number of sessions with huge values. Causing the heap to fill resulting in outofmemory error and crashing the whole servlet container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i decided to only do a check on string length.

Most of the security concerns are related on how a servlet container/app server implements the way it handles sessions. This does seem to differ from container to container.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you do with it. Just having a user defined value in the session shouldn't be much of a risk, unless the container has bugs.

This doesn't mean it's a good idea to let users put anything they want in the session because, for example, containers *do* have bugs.

Comment: Cheers Kayaman, i'm a bit confused about how far i should go with checking the value that goes in to the session. I guess limiting the size of a string is a good idea. But should i look at the content? One thing comes in mind is the whole serialization bug some time ago, servlet containers likely serialize/deserialize sessions at some point (for example shutdown startup or distributing sessions in cluster). Isn't it possible user puts "bad" serialization code in the session when i just look at the size?

Comment: What's "bad serialization code"? I was assuming we're talking about the user sticking text into the session. It's not like you can achieve something like SQL injection with just that.

Comment: Yes, it indeed is text. But i don't know if you can put "bad things" in text that does "bad things" when serialized/processed by the servlet container or handled by other related processes in a container. Note that i asked this question because i don't know if that is at all possible. I did hope somebody else did know. On a side note the bad serialization code was related to the use of certain technology in commons lang library where bad serialization code could execute user code. That would be worst then sql injection.

Comment: The serialization (or rather deserialization) bug was a lot more complex and required you to get access to serialized data and fiddle with custom `readObject()` methods and other such things if I recall correctly. It would be a gigantic flaw if the serialization mechanism would serialize text into something that would become harmful when deserialized (or serialized).